# Prevent font changing for password visible field

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

After adding: `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"` to my `EditText` I found out, that font is changed to some `Monospaced font` on first focus.

Is there any way to change this behavior, i.e. by changing style of `EditTexts`?